# How to checkout without js In magento?

Tags: php, javascript, magento, checkout

It is possible to checkout without js in on onepage checkout page in magento, because all processes are done with ajax call so if there is any feasibility to remove js from checkout?

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to disable the **onepage checkout**.

Then you have the normal way.

**System->Configuration**, Click on **Checkout** under **SALES** you find **Checkout Options**

But i think the most people have JS and activated.

Comment: yes i want to onepage checkout enable but its work without js

Comment: Even the multipage checkout depends on javascript for things like card validation. Magento was built on the prototype framework and unless you're willing to expend a lot of effort de-ajaxifying and rewriting the cart, you're not going to divorce Magento from javascript any time soon.

Comment: yes i know  but i just want any idea if there is any feasibility to doing this

Comment: I don't think that there is a message. You can build the whole process on your own. But i think that need to much time.

Comment: but suppose we remove ajax call and assign action direct to the form action

Comment: Perhaps its possible but you need a lot of time for a new extension. But i don't understand why you make it so complicated and don't use the normal way.